# Accessing Data from my axios get response not working

Tags: reactjs, .net, typescript, axios

can someone point out where am going wrong?
I have a simple API get request. this get data fine from my API

```
const GetMedicalPackages = async (props:IGetMedPack)=>{
    const token = props.token
   
    const data = axios({
        method:"get",
        responseType:"json",
        url : baseURL + "medicalPackage", 
        headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}
      })
      await data;
      return data.then((response:IMedicalPackageData| undefined)=>{
        return response
      })
 
}
```

This returns data like this
[Data from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tVV7.png)

Now trying to access the data with this code returns with this code always returns and undefined

```
useEffect(() => {
    //async function fetchMyData() {
    GetMedicalPackages({ token }).then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        const options = response.data.map((row) => {
          console.log(row.MedicalInsurancePackage);
          return row.MedicalInsurancePackage;
          //console.log(row);
          //options.push(row.MedicalInsurancePackage);
        });
        //setMedPackage(options);
        console.log(options, response.data);
      }
    });
```

[options values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eexp.png)

I suspect it to do with the object that returned in each row but i might be wrong.
Can someone point out what is wrong please thanks

I have tried foreach and various techniques but nothing.
to get the array of strings

Just for clarity, The problem is not the axios call giving me the data. I can see data fine. But try to use the data returned is the problem. console log shows me the data. but as soon i try to map it i get undefines. Please see images
console log row give me this

activePackage: true
medicalInsurancePackage: "Standard"
medicalInsurancePackageDesc: "S Standard"
medicalInsurancePackageID:1
[[Prototype]]:Object

but console log row.medicalInsurancePackage give me undifined

Comment: Your function `GetMedicalPackages` returns a `IMedicalPackageData` yes? that's an object and not an array, so you can use `.map` on it.
Also you can just use `const data = await axios(...);` and delete everything after.

Comment: this still gives me the same problem. I get the data but cannot do a map on it

Comment: Woops sorry I meant `can't` use map on an object. Ah but your axios call does return an array :) add `:IMedicalPackageData[]` as return type to make it clear (i see you already solved the problem, just some friendly advice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your are missunderstanding how `Promise` are working. consider doing:

```js
const GetMedicalPackages = async (props) => {
  const token = props.token;

  return await axios({
    method: "get",
    responseType: "json",
    url : baseURL + "medicalPackage",
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  });
};
```

Comment: Doing it this way  still doesn't fix the problem of me not been able to map the data. I still get undefines in my map

Comment: This is fixing your actual question on Stackoverflow. To fix this new problem, can you try to `console.log(row)` rather than `console.log(row.MedicalInsurancePackage)`

Comment: Yes console log row shows the data. But when am trying to fix is the undefines when i try to map the data

Comment: can you show me the structure of your `row` response ?

Comment: console log row give me this

**activePackage: true,**
**medicalInsurancePackage: "Standard" ,**
**medicalInsurancePackageDesc: "S Standard" ,**
**medicalInsurancePackageID:1,**
**[[Prototype]]:Object**

but console log **row.medicalInsurancePackage** give me **undifined**

Comment: ok. replace `row.MedicalInsurancePackage` by `row.medicalInsurancePackage ` (lowercase first letter). If it worked. consider accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks. changed my interface to lowercase first letter, then replaced it where it was been used. that worked. 
Why did the return data not conform to the interface

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be `await`ing your variable, but should be awaiting for the result of your `axios` call. And then just return the response you get from it.

```
const data = await axios(...)
return data;
```

Comment: This still gives me the same problem. I get the data but can do a map on it and its returns undefined